# Oracle 10g: Is it possible to designate a undo point?

Tags: oracle, oracle-10g, restore

I was wondering if it is possible to designate a point in time, then later "roll-it-back" to that state (undo DDL and DML changes). Maybe using a record of changes and then executing the reverse? Does Oracle have any features like this built in 10g or 11g?

Thanks in advance,

Kyle

Answer (score 5, accepted):

John has pointed you at the Flashback Query options useful from a developers point of view. If I read you correctly then you are probably looking for the Flashback Database and Restore Point functionality documented [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/backup.102/b14192/rpfbdb001.htm#BABBBBIC) which allows you to do precisely this. Flashback Database does have some requirements over and above the flashback query functionality (for example it requires a flash recovery area to be configured and extra disk space compared to a non-flashback database ).

Comment: Yep, this is what I'm looking for 100%. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Take a look into flashback [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28424/adfns_flashback.htm). I think it was introduced in 10g and can be utilised to bring a table back to an earlier state, for example.